# Make a Search Box that will Search a Websites Text in HTML

Tags: html

So I need to have a search box search through text on a web page and show relevant searches. I have no clue how to do this and didn't find anything online on how to. So if I have a search box on www.example.com/index.html, and and user enters text into it, then it searches the text on www.example.com/example.html and displays the result. Finally just an FIY it needs to be in HTML. Thanks for any help in advanced!

Comment: Impossible, in HTML...

Comment: You can't do this in HTML, you will need Javascript or PHP for this

Comment: And without seeing your own attempts (I don't, for a second, believe you could find something relevant to implementing this, with JavaScript, on the internet) it's 'too broad' at best.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you would need to know javascript (and probably php) to do that properly, which your request sounds like you do not.

If you need to add a search engine without knowing javascript/php, then your best bet is probably to look into something like Google's Custom Search - https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2630969?hl=en

Setting it up sounds simple enough for someone who doesn't understand what the code is actually doing - all copy and paste.  Don't do that with any old script on the web, though.  There's plenty of dodgy ones out there!

Comment: Ok then, I am willing to learn some PhP and Javascript to do this. Now can I have some code examples, because by the next time I come back to check this, I will probably know the basics.